# Android: Background on SurfaceView?

Tags: android, surfaceview

I have a surface view, and whenever I touch the screen, an image comes up in the spot I touch. It's great, but I cannot figure out how to put a background on the SurfaceView. I have tried using the OnDraw to draw a background right away (Without having to touch it), and that only works some of the time. It force closes most of the time.

Would anyone want to look at my code and see if it's possible to get a background image on the Surface view? Thanks in advance.

> class MyView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
>     private Thready _thread;
>     private ArrayList _graphicsz = new ArrayList();
>       private GraphicObject _currentGraphic = null;

```
public MyView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
    _thread = new Thready(getHolder(), this);
    setFocusable(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    synchronized (_thread.getSurfaceHolder()) {
        GraphicObject graphic = null;
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            graphic = new GraphicObject(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.cat1small));
            graphic.getCoordinates().setX((int) event.getX() - graphic.getGraphic().getWidth() / 2);
            graphic.getCoordinates().setY((int) event.getY() - graphic.getGraphic().getHeight() / 2);
            _currentGraphic = graphic;
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            _currentGraphic.getCoordinates().setX((int) event.getX() - _currentGraphic.getGraphic().getWidth() / 2);
            _currentGraphic.getCoordinates().setY((int) event.getY() - _currentGraphic.getGraphic().getHeight() / 2);
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            _graphicsz.add(_currentGraphic);
            _currentGraphic = null;
        }

        return true;
    }
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {


    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
    Bitmap bitmap1;
    GraphicObject.Coordinates coords1;
    for (GraphicObject graphic : _graphicsz) {
        bitmap1 = graphic.getGraphic();
        coords1 = graphic.getCoordinates();
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap1, coords1.getX(), coords1.getY(), null);
    }
    // draw current graphic at last...
    if (_currentGraphic != null) {
        bitmap1 = _currentGraphic.getGraphic();
        coords1 = _currentGraphic.getCoordinates();
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap1, coords1.getX(), coords1.getY(), null);
    }
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    _thread.setRunning(true);
    _thread.start();
}




public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // simply copied from sample application LunarLander:
    // we have to tell thread to shut down & wait for it to finish, or else
    // it might touch the Surface after we return and explode
    boolean retry = true;
    _thread.setRunning(false);
    while (retry) {
        try {
            _thread.join();
            retry = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // we will try it again and again...
        }
    }
}
```

> }
>
> class Thready extends Thread {
>     private SurfaceHolder _surfaceHolder;
>    private MyView _panel;
>   private boolean _run = false;

```
public Thready(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, MyView panel) {
    _surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
    _panel = panel;
}

public void setRunning(boolean run) {
    _run = run;
}

public SurfaceHolder getSurfaceHolder() {
    return _surfaceHolder;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    Canvas c;
    while (_run) {
        c = null;
        try {
            c = _surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
            synchronized (_surfaceHolder) {
                _panel.onDraw(c);
            }
        } finally {
            // do this in a finally so that if an exception is thrown
            // during the above, we don't leave the Surface in an
            // inconsistent state
            if (c != null) {
                _surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> }
>
> class GraphicObject {
>     /**
>     * Contains the coordinates of the graphic.
>    */
>   public class Coordinates {
>     private int _x = 100;
>           private int _y = 0;

```
    public int getX() {
        return _x + _bitmap.getWidth() / 2;
    }

    public void setX(int value) {
        _x = value - _bitmap.getWidth() / 2;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return _y + _bitmap.getHeight() / 2;
    }

    public void setY(int value) {
        _y = value - _bitmap.getHeight() / 2;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Coordinates: (" + _x + "/" + _y + ")";
    }
}

private Bitmap _bitmap;
private Coordinates _coordinates;

public GraphicObject(Bitmap bitmap) {
    _bitmap = bitmap;
    _coordinates = new Coordinates();
}

public Bitmap getGraphic() {
    return _bitmap;
}

public Coordinates getCoordinates() {
    return _coordinates;
}
```

> }

Answer (score 0):

Well, what strikes me first off all (and what could be causing a lot of problem) is this:

you're creating new bitmap way too often

Every time you get a touch event, you're loading in your bitmaps ... and you can get 80 to 100 touchevents every second!

So to start with, define global bitmaps (private Bitmap bmp1; etc), load them somewhere else and THEN use them in your touch event.

Also, remove the bmp loading/creation from onDraw and move it to somewhere else.

After you've done that, see what happens; you might have more problems (a REALY quick scan of your code seemed fine), but not creating and loading bitmaps 80 times a second will definitely help out :)